# Bevel miter outer to arch creates artifacts

Tags: bevel, artifacts

How can I remove artifacts that appear when I set bevel miter outer to arch type?
In this example, I cut a hole in a cube and then applied bevel modifier. When I set miter outer to arch, some artifacts line appear from any miter outer point to the face other edge.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you checked "harden normals"

[image]

and autosmooth

[image]